# Sign up with Google+

Tags: authentication, oauth, social-networking

Is there any implementation of a "Sign up with Google+" out there? The same way as we can sign up with Twitter, Facebook or Linkedin? I don't see anything in their API docs about it.

Comment: I think it's the same as signing up w gmail

Answer (score 0):

Just use the *sign-up with Google* one: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html